# VBA Do (delete column where find is true) Until Find is False then exit do

Tags: vba, loops

I have an excel file that has the text "Income from Trans" where I will need to delete the entire column.

This is my current code in VBA 2010 that works until there are no more cells with "Income from Trans"; I can't get it to break out of the loop.

Any idea why?

```
Dim rng1 As Range
Dim target1 As String

target1 = "Income From    Trans"
Set rng1 = Cells.Find(What:=target1, _
After:=ActiveCell, _
LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
LookAt:=xlPart, _
SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
MatchCase:=False)

Do Until rng1 Is Nothing
    Cells.Find(What:=target1, After:=ActiveCell, _
        LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, 
SearchDirection _
         :=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
ActiveCell.EntireColumn.Delete
Loop
```

Comment: You never change rng1 inside your loop, so how could it ever end?

Answer (score 0):

Check the search result inside the loop as well

---

```
Dim rng1 As Range, target1 As String, firstFound As String

target1 = "Income From    Trans"

Set rng1 = Cells.Find(What:=target1, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                      LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                      SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)

If Not rng1 Is Nothing Then

    Do

        firstFound = rng1.Address

        Set rng1 = Cells.Find(What:=target1, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlValues, _
                              LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                              SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, _
                              SearchFormat:=False)

        If Not rng1 Is Nothing Then rng1.EntireColumn.Delete

    Loop While Not rng1 Is Nothing And rng1.Address <> firstFound

End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code `Set rng1 = Cells.Find...` will set `rng1` to be a range object, assuming it finds your value. Next is your loop which will ultimately cause `rng1` to be deleted. It continues to loop because even though `rng1` is deleted it still was assigned and therefore isn't `Nothing`. It ends with an [run time error message of 91](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/object-variable-not-set-error-91) because `rng1` was set but deleted. You can see in the locals window View>Locals Window that its type is still `Range\Range` even though it's actually been deleted.

You have implicit cell references from the unqualified `Cells` usage. That means this code will run on whatever worksheet happens to be the `ActiveSheet`. Implicit references can have unintended side effects when you don't realize this. It's best to fully qualify them so there's no ambiguity as to which sheet they reside on. I'm assuming `ActiveCell` falls into this category too since you want it to wrap delete until there "Income from Trans" is no longer found.

The code `.Activate` followed by `ActiveCell.` isn't needed and can be shortened by removing both so it ends up as `SearchFormat:=False).EntireColum...`. Selecting a range object isn't usually necessary. Joining the two makes it apparent what you're doing.

Below you'll find a simpler version that uses `.Find` is in your original to find the first instance. After that it uses [.FindNext()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-findnext-method-excel) to continue looping until all are found. This eventually exits because it is setting the range variable `found` after every deletion, ultimately leaving `found` as `Nothing` after it's deleted the last. The `RemoveColumns` has parameters which allow you to use this on more than just a single sheet.

```
Sub Test()
    RemoveColumns Sheet1, "Income From    Trans"
End Sub

Sub RemoveColumns(ByVal sheetToSearch As Worksheet, ByVal value As String)
    Dim found As Range
    Set found = sheetToSearch.Cells.Find(What:=value, After:=sheetToSearch.Range("A1"), LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                                LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                                MatchCase:=False)
    Do Until found Is Nothing
        found.EntireColumn.Delete
        Set found = sheetToSearch.Cells.FindNext
    Loop
End Sub
```